# Can you please explain to me why it is specified that the kalki avatar is going to kill people of mixed castes and kings born of sudra women?

Tags: vishnu, kalki, vayupurana

As per Vayu Purana I.58.76-83:

> “He will be called Pramiti. He was born of a part of Visnu formerly in the Svayambhuva Manvantara. He wandered over the earth for full twenty years. He led an army consisting of cavalry, chariots and elephants. He was surrounded by hundreds and thousands of Brahmanas armed with weapons. He killed Mlecchas in thousands. He went everywhere. **After killing the kings born of Sudra women, he exterminated the heretics.** He killed thousands of persons who were not religious and righteous. **He killed those born of mixed castes as well as those who depended on them.** He killed the Udicyas (northerners), Madya Desyas (people of the Middle Land), mountain-dwellers, easterners, westerners, dwellers in Vindhya and Aparanta. He killed the southerners, Dravidas, Simhalas, Gandharas, Paradas, Pahlavas, Yavanas, Tusaras, Barbaras, Cinas, Sulikas, Daradas, Khasas, Lampakas, Ketas, and the different tribes of Kratas.”

Can anyone please explain to me the reason behind the killing of kings born to sudra women and the killing of people of mixed castes by Kalki avatar of Lord Vishnu?

Comment: it's like burning the old dead forest so that new growth can begin fresh. at end of kali yuga, mostly only mixed born people exist who are confused about their interests and profession so creating the 4-varna system fresh in krita yuga will help the world gain order.